# Are there any mock Youtube accounts that can be used to test the youtube analytics api?

Tags: youtube, youtube-analytics-api

I've been looking at using the Youtube Analytics API to create a web app for Youtube users to find out their channel trends, forecasts, etc.

I do not have a Youtube account, and if I made one, it would have no content. 
Are there any mock accounts that can be used for testing the API functionalities?
If not, how can I go about testing my app as if I was the user?

P.S. by content I mean data such as ad revenue/earnings, views, viewer demographics, etc

Thanks!

Comment: Make one and add some sample content to it?

Comment: As in make an account and add videos? Sure, but what about other data such as ad revenue, video views, viewer demographics, etc?
I feel like I'd need access to an account that has been around for a while and has had some exposure.